# Display vector tiles (PBF) in Leaflet after exporting from QGIS

Tags: qgis, leaflet, vector-tiles

Loading a vector tiles in leaflet with `leaflet.vectorgrid` I'm getting `Error: unknown command 4`

core code that fails:

```
var pbf_testSlope = new L.vectorGrid.protobuf('https://myx.ch/test/Slope_Ausschnitt_WGS84/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf',
            vectorTileOptions = {
            interactive: true,
            maxNativeZoom: 16,
             vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                    fill: true,
                    weight: 1,
                    fillColor: 'red',
                    color: '#06cccc',
                    fillOpacity: 0.2,
                    opacity: 0.4,
                    }
                
            }
```

The aim is to include a large polygon dataset in a leaflet-map.
For testing purposes, I exported a smaller set to our local webserver using
`native:writevectortiles_xyz` in QGIS. QGIS can access the server well under the following URL:
https://myx.ch/test/Slope_Ausschnitt_WGS84/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf

However, I struggle to get that working in a leaflet app.

```
Error: unknown command 4
    at VectorTileFeature$2.loadGeometry (vectortilefeature.js:81:19)
    at Leaflet.VectorGrid.Protobuf.js:141:27
```

Sometimes I'm getting as well `unknown command 6`.

Nothing is displayed in the leaflet app.

Here is a sample leaflet HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@latest/dist/leaflet.css">
        <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map">
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@latest/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.wms@latest/dist/leaflet.wms.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.vectorgrid@latest/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js"></script>

        <script>

        var map = L.map('map', {
            zoomControl:true, maxZoom:28, minZoom:1
        }).fitBounds([
            [47.1247804242369881, 8.1082769014031886],
            [47.1277594260495789, 8.1132427183521294]
        ])


        map.createPane('pane_SWISSIMAGEHintergrund_3');
        map.getPane('pane_SWISSIMAGEHintergrund_3').style.zIndex = 100;
        var layer_SWISSIMAGEHintergrund_3 = L.WMS.layer("https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?VERSION=1.3.0", "ch.swisstopo.swissimage", {
            pane: 'pane_SWISSIMAGEHintergrund_3',
            format: 'image/jpeg',
            uppercase: true,
            transparent: true,
            continuousWorld : true,
            tiled: true,
            info_format: 'text/html',
            opacity: 1,
            identify: false,
            attribution: 'Swisstopo',
        });


        map.createPane('pbf_Test');
        map.getPane('pbf_Test').style.zIndex = 450;
        //map.getPane('pbf_Test').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'multiply';
        var pbf_testSlope = new L.vectorGrid.protobuf('http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://myx.ch/test/Slope_Ausschnitt_WGS84/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf',
            vectorTileOptions = {
            interactive: true,
            maxNativeZoom: 16,
             vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                    fill: true,
                    weight: 1,
                    fillColor: 'red',
                    color: '#06cccc',
                    fillOpacity: 0.2,
                    opacity: 0.4,
                    }
                
            }  
        );


        map.addLayer(layer_SWISSIMAGEHintergrund_3);

        L.control.layers(   {"SWISSIMAGE Hintergrund": layer_SWISSIMAGEHintergrund_3},
                            {'Slope PBF':pbf_testSlope},
                            ).addTo(map);


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---- new information
I tried with QGIS 3.34.4 (LTR). It's getting better, but still fails in several locations. It now seems to be like other errors I've seen. At least, I'm getting other errors now :)
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`

[image]

Comment: If I try it with `L.vectorGrid.protobuf` in Leaflet I get error `Error: unknown command 4` from vector tile parser. If I try it in OpenLayers I can display tiles without problems, so obviously there is something in pbf tiles that `L.vectorGrid.protobuf` does not recognize.

Comment: Many thanks. Could it be that `native:writevectortiles_xyz` compresses the pbf?

Comment: That could be one possibility. I even looked at the content of the pbf tile, but I'm not expert in this field and can't differentiate between compressed and uncompressed tiles.

Comment: the unknown command 4 points to compression as a potential issue - it might think they are compressed but are not or vice versa